# Are there any Application Lifecycle Managment tool like Mylyn or tasktop?

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any tool in ubuntu for connecting development, QA, and project management, something which  provides synchronization solution for enterprise-scale application LifeCycle management,

For example : mylyn and Tasktop;

Some logical way to integrate web activity(ie, emailing/time spend on researching on a topic) and other system development activities and associating each part of activity with other relevant seed of thought.

So that in end if we find one stream of thought we can track different activities related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Tasktop will work very happily on Ubuntu.  Tasktop is built on top of Eclipse, which aims to be completely cross-platform.  (Eclipse probably won't run on Commodore 64s, but it will run on just about every major contemporary platform.)

I haven't tried in a while, but I ran Eclipse 3.3 and Mylyn on my home Hardy Heron laptop quite regularly two or three years ago.  (I ran it all day long on my work SUSE machine.)

Disclaimer: I recently started working for Tasktop.  I did not two or three years ago.

Comment: I have also worked in Tasktop applications before, Is there any open source version of [Tasktop Sync Solution];

Comment: There are no open source versions of Tasktop Sync Solution.